# UILocalNotification in iOS 9 of iBeacon app tips sound 2 times but just one notifaciton in list

Tags: ios, ios9, ibeacon

It's very strange in iOS9 again. This one is in my iBeacon app. When i had sent  location notification just one time but got the tips sound 2 times in - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region.

If i send local notification outside the didDetermineState or in iOS8 and it tips sound just one time.

Very weird and whatever i use presentLocalNotificationNow or scheduledLocalNotifications and all got the same problem.

I will go crazy for iOS9.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer. If i try to execute registerUserNotificationSettings twice in iOS9. YES, i will got tips sound twice in one local notification.
Mabybe it's a bug of iOS9.

Answer (score 0):

ever since ios8 some additional internal filtering is applied. We here noticed the same with many of our apps :/

we never found out the logic or any kind of workaround...